# Does "sb's ass" have a special meaning here, or just mean sb him/herself?

Tags: idioms, meaning-in-context, slang, cinema

It may be a stupid question on this site, but it is somewhat bothering me:

---

WARNING: containing strong language.

---

In the movie *Pulp Fiction*, the character Marsellus Wallace says to Butch:

> You see, this profession is filled to the brim with unrealistic motherfuckers. Motherfuckers who thought *their ass* would age like wine. If you mean *it* turns to vinegar, *it* does. If you mean *it* gets better with age, *it* don't.

Clearly, *it* refers to *their ass*, then what does *their ass* refer to? Does it just refer to *unrealistic motherfuckers*? If it does, then for the last two lines, will it be equivalent to say:

> If you mean *they* (motherduckers) turn to vinegar, *they* do. If you mean *they* get better with age, *it* don't.

?

Or, is it the case that only an "ass" could turn to vinegar, but a human can't...?

Comment: butt, keister, bum, posterior, buttocks...but, by figurative extension, they themselves ("who thought [they] would age like wine"). So, to paraphrase, 'If they thought they would become sour [like vinegar], they were correct. If they thought they would improve with age, they were wrong.' Another sense (and no reason to exclude more than one, because the speaker is rambling from idea to idea), is that "it" refers to 'their life' or 'life' in general. To paraphrase: "If you mean your life goes sour, it does. If you mean your life gets better, it doesn't.'

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Literally, *ass* would mean their sexual appeal and performance.  It can be extended to mean *your game*:

> This profession is filled to the brim with unrealistic jerks. Jerks who thought their game would get better as they age.

Comment: Accepted answer, three down votes and no explanatory comment.  Help me understand what's wrong with this Answer, please.